# love2d error: attempt to call field drawq (a nil value)

Tags: lua, love2d

```
 require("AnAL")
function love.load()
   local c=love.graphics.newImage("coin.png")
   a=newAnimation(c, 578, 578, 0.2, 0)
end

function love.update(dt)
   a:update(dt)   
end

function love.draw()
   a:draw(100, 100) 
end
```

this is a simple program to show in the screen a animation, but when I try to run, i receive a error message:

```
AnAL.lua:92: attempt to call field 'drawq'(a nil value)
traceback
AnAL.lua:92: in function 'draw'
main.lua:12: in function 'draw'
[c]: in function 'xpcall'
```

what's wrong?

I using the love 0.9.2

Answer (score 2):

You should show us your `newAnimation` and `a:draw` but most likely you get error because you try to call `drawq` which was removed in **0.9.0**.

Check [love.graphics.drawq](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.drawq) in documentation.

`drawq` functionality was moved to [love.graphics.draw](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.draw#Function_2).